# symfony fosuserBundle, unable to send confirmation mail after registration

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Symfony seems to be unable to send confirmation mail, this is my code
I tried everything but no result.

This is the code of **config.yml**:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: BackOfficeBundle\Entity\User
    service:                               
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            from_email:
                address: '%mailer_user%'
                sender_name: '%mailer_user%'   
    from_email:
        address:  '%mailer_user%'
        sender_name: '%mailer_user%'
```

This is the code of  **parameters.yml**:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: fos
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_auth_mode: login
    mailer_encryption: ssl
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: mail.mail@gmail.com
    mailer_password: 000000
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

This is the code of  **config_dev.yml**:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  '%mailer_user%'
    password:  '%mailer_password%'
```

[The user is created and in description it said that i should check my email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQElO.png)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked var/log/dev.log for any errors? Are you working with the web profiler toolbar? Does it show any errors?

Comment: Have you read the paragraph about the Gmail account security configuration at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/gmail.html)? [Off topic: In the dev environment - config_dev.yml - I think it's good practice to add Swiftmailer's "delivery_addresses" option to catch emails.]

Comment: @Philippe-B thnx for replying i did not see the part Gmail account security

Comment: even though 2-step process is desactivated in my google account there is no mail!!

Comment: Have you allowed less secure apps to access your Gmail account too? BTW, I hope it's not your personal account. If it is, you should reactivate the 2-step authentication and use another account created just for this.

Comment: ok i will try this thnx for your reply :)

Comment: You haven't replied to @Emil, have you checked your logs? You could also try to send an email via command line with the command `swiftmailer:email:send` and see how it goes.

Comment: @Philippe-B- i was able to send email via swiftmailer:email:send

Comment: @Emil i was unable to see any errors in my var/log/dev.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue probably comes from the fact that you're testing in a local environment without a valid certificate, thus you can't establish a secure connection to the Gmail server.

To make it work, try to:

- Configure the Gmail account (it's preferable not to use your personal account) by creating an app password and allowing access to less secure apps, as described at the bottom of [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/email/gmail.html).
- Add the `verify_peer` option set to `false` in the swiftmailer configuration:

```
#config_dev.yml

swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  '%mailer_user%'
    password:  '%mailer_password%'
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            verify_peer: false
```

> Note that this setup is not secure and should only be used in the dev
>   environment for quick tests without sensitive data. You should also add the `delivery_addresses` option in swiftmailer configuration to send all mails to one address.

Comment: thnx, now i was able to send email, why these infos does not exist in official docuemntation??